# Can I trigger date(time) picker from a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a select with 20 options and when user **selects only one particular option "Select date time"** the date(time) picker should appear and **then populate the date time text in a input box**.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

I have date(picker) working right now. It is triggered by button and linked to a input box. But I want to modify how it works currently to my specific needs.

**Question1:** I know how to fire a function onchange of select. Then I filter the options and if it is the one I will somehow start date picker. I do not know how to do this part.

**Question2:** I do not know how to tell date picker to add the date text into existing text box. Maybe I can link the date timer picker with the text box somehow.

- jquery-1.7.2.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js
- jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

## Update

In the [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/dPRjS/3/) I have select and text box. The button is created by date/time picker.

What I want is:

- when user selects/clicks the "select date and time" option the date/time picker will appear and the text will be in the text box
- I don't want the button to be visible on the page
- I use the text box for other purposes not only for the date/time so the date/time picker cannot appear by any user action related to this text box

html code from the sample

```
<input id="datetime" type="text" name="datetime" value="" >
<select size=5>
    <option value="not">Not this one</option>
    <option value="not">Not this one</option>
    <option value="not">Not this one</option>
    <option value="datetimepicker">Select date and time</option>
</select>
```

javascript code from the sample

```
$('#datetime').datetimepicker({
    showOn: "button"
});​
```

​Note: final working version as described above: http://jsfiddle.net/radek/dPRjS/8/

Comment: Please post the code you have. A jsFiddle would be helpful too.

Comment: jsfiddle and sample code added

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#datetime').datetimepicker();
$('option[value=datetimepicker]').click(function() {
    $('#datetime').datetimepicker('show');
});​
```

To answer your core question, the datetimepicker plugin is an extension of the datepicker jQueryUI widget and has access to all of its methods, including the show method. So you can programmatically call the show to open the picker whenever you need to.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dPRjS/5/)**.

Comment: Works nicely but the picker appears also if I click the text box. It shouldn't.

Comment: So take the call off the button.

Answer (score 1):

answering your questions in reverse order....

Datepicker is normally "attached" to an input box. There is no need to tell datepicker to put its selected date into the input box.  The datepicker just does so, when it closes, which is when the user selects a date.

That leaves the trick of how to open a datepicker based on some external event. Normally the datepicker opens automatically with a click in the attached input box.  You want it to open automatically with a change of a select/dropdown.

This worked for me:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dp = $('#date1').datepicker({});

  $('#select1').change(function() {
      // programmatically open the datepicker
      $dp.datepicker('show'); 
  });
});
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="date1" size="12">
<br/>
<select id="select1">
  <option>Hello</option>
  <option>Bonjour</option>
  <option>Buon giorno</option>
  <option>Guten tag</option>
</select>
```